# Is "to ask a question" redundant?

Tags: sentence-structure, redundancy

Isn't it enough to just *ask*, instead of *to ask a question*?

Which one should be preferable?

Comment: I'd say this is less of an English question and more of a personal preference and etiquette question that varies between different countries, cultures, contexts, and people, and probably can't be answered here.

Comment: You **need** "a question" because *ask* is transitive.

Comment: @user178049 couldn't​ your comment be an answer?

Comment: @user178049 I think that a verb is transitive does not necessarily mean it has to be followed by an object. Objects can be omitted too. You probably heard "I sing in the bath".

Comment: @Cardinal It is true that a transitive verb doesn't always followed by a verb, especially in a hollow clause "This is hard to keep_"; fronted object "some thing you like_, but some thing you don't". But "sing" in your example is actually intransitive.

Comment: @user178049 You can check "Cambridge Advanced Grammer in Use, Unite 28, Section B, M.Hewings" for that sing example.

Comment: @Cardinal I don't have that book, unfortunately. But I think "sing" is intransitive here, see [1.a](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sing). Btw, I notice some funny errors in my previous comment.. Err.

Comment: @user178049 No it's not, "I sing (songs) in the bath" The object is implied though not being mentioned. Regarding the book, you can use google.

Comment: @user178049 Yes.

Answer (score 2):

"ask" in this particular context is transitive. So it takes an object.

"I ask **a question**."

*ask* would be intransitive when you say to (someone) that you want them to do or give something.

"Don't be afraid to ask for advice"

For more, see [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ask)

Comment: Yes, indeed you need to specify what you want to ask. *A question* in this particular context. BTW :+1

Answer (score 2):

If you say

> I asked.

people will realize you asked a question, but they will wonder *About what*? and certainly when one is *asking* about something one is posing a question.

> Ask for permission
>   Ask for advice
>   Ask for someone's hand in marriage

In situations like those, the secondary effects are what people are interested in.  For example,

> P1: Was he asking for directions?
>   P2: No, just asking a question.

So it is not necessarily redundant to say

> I asked a question.

but there is usually additional context which gets added

> I asked a question *about*...